# How reliable are Django Signals?

Tags: django, django-signals

Have some questions regarding Django Signals in general:

- Is there a possibility that signals are sent more than once?
- Is there a possibility that signals don't fire?
- Is there a way to ensure that signals are sent once and once only?
- Is there a way to "replay" the signal without replaying the actual event?
- Is there a package that stores Django signals in the DB to act as a history?
- Is there a package that can auto-retry signals that fail, kinda like webhooks with exponential backoffs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A lot of Django ORM calls circumvent signals, like `.update(..)`, `.bulk_create(..)`, `.bulk_update(..)`, etc. In fact Django signals are a bit of an antipattern in *most* cases: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: Furthermore signals are not like a RabbitMQ queue or something similar. It is more an observer pattern.